# Getting the solution of less general differential equation from the general one

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a differential equation
$$y''=-ay\tag{1}$$
The solution to this is
$$y=B\cos(ax)+C\sin(ax)$$

But if
$$y''=0\tag{2}$$
Then we have

$$y=A'x+B'$$

Since (2) is a sought of less general form of (1), I expect the solution of (2) to be derived from soultion of (1).

So if we set $a=0$ in solution of (1) we get

$$y=B\tag{3}$$

Thus we loose the linear term of the full solution. If instead of saying $a=0$, we say that $a\approx0$, then in the limit where $ax\approx 0$ as well, we get

$$y=Cax+B= Dx+B$$

where $D=Ca$

Why does this happen, that is why can't we get the full solution by assuming $a=0$ in the solution of (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question and the reasoning behind it is subtle. The solution to $y'' + ay = 0$ can be broken into two cases: $a\neq0$ and $a=0$.

If we denote the differentiation operator as $D$, then the differential equation can be written in the following way: $$(D + i\sqrt{a})(D-i\sqrt{a})y=0.$$
In the case when $a\neq0$, this is satisfied by either $(D+i\sqrt{a})y=0$ or $(D-i\sqrt{a})y=0$, which yield $y = e^{\mp i\sqrt{a}x}$, respectively. When $a=0$, we no longer have two different differential operators that tell us the two components that comprise our general solution

When $a\neq 0$, the general solution is $$y(x) = Ae^{i\sqrt{a}x} + Be^{-i\sqrt{a}x}.$$ This comes from the fact that $\pm i\sqrt{a}$ are the roots of $r^2 + a=0$. When $a>0$, we get complex exponentials, which are equivalent to sines and cosines. When $a<0$, we will get $i^2$ in the exponents, and our solutions will be pure real exponentials. The key here is that the roots of $r^2+a=0$ are distinct.

This fails when $a=0$. Here, the only root is $0$, but it is a double root. In this case, the differential equation becomes $y''=0,$ which can be satisfied in *exactly* two ways:

1. $y'=0\implies y=c$.
2. $y''=0$, but $y'\neq 0\implies y'=c\neq 0$.

Combining both of these solutions yields $y=cx+d$.

Intuitively, it doesn't make much sense for the general form of the solution to change drastically as $a$ crosses zero, but the multiplicity of the roots of $r^2+a=0$ jumps from $1$ to $2$ then back to $1$ as $a$ crosses zero, hence the change in solution behavior.

Answer (score 3):

We can get the $a=0$ case as a **limit** of the $a \ne 0$ case, using l'Hopital's rule.

Solution of $y''=-ay$ when $a \ne 0$
$$
B\cos (ax) + C\sin (ax).
\tag1$$
With initial conditions $y(0)=P, y'(0)=Q$, we substitute in $(1)$ and get solution
$$
y_a(x) = P \cos(ax) + \frac{Q}{a}\sin(ax) .
\tag2$$
Now in $(2)$ take limit as $a \to 0$...
$$
\lim_{a\to 0}y_a(x) = \lim_{a\to 0}\big(P \cos(ax) + \frac{Q}{a}\sin(ax)\big)
$$
Use l'Hopital's rule on $\sin(ax)/a$,
$$
\lim_{a\to 0}y_a(x) = P+Qx =: y_0(x)
$$
This is the solution to $y''=0, y(0)=P, y'(0)=Q$.

Comment: A simiilar trick lets us get $\int x^{-1}\;dx$ as a limit of integrals $\int x^a\,dx$ with $a \ne -1$.

Comment: Pretty neat way!

Comment: This limit also works if you let $a\to0$ from the other side and make sure to write the general solution in terms of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$.